# La etiqueta php.mysql debería eliminarse

Tags: discusión, solicitud-de-quemado

La etiqueta [php.mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php.mysql) se creó como resultado de un error del autor al crear la pregunta

[Valor por default a un input en HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7513/valor-por-default-a-un-input-en-html)

Edité la pregunta y coloqué las etiquetas correctas pero no puedo eliminar la etiqueta erronea y es posible que alguien más se la ponga a su pregunta por accidente.

Creo que debería ser eliminada cuanto antes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según este post del meta en inglés [meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/158172](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/158172) los tags que no tienen preguntas asociadas son eliminados automáticamente de manera diaria.

No es necesario hacer una solicitud para borrar etiquetas, simplemente corregir el nombre.

Answer (score 1):

He revisado la pregunta pero veo que dicha etiqueta ya no existe.